# smarty how to replace exist char(php added) to judgment display image or display other column

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

have a database table include two column "brand_logo",and column "brand_name"
column "brand_logo" only put jpg file name(string) like

```
"logo.jpg"
```

column "brand_name" only put store name(string) like

```
"northwind_store_name"
```

i hope if not exist store logo image value("brand_logo")
then alter to only show store name

code like
**php part**

```
$tmp["Data"] = "data/brandlogo/" . $brand["brand_logo"];
```

**smarty template part**

```
<div>
{assign "bgImg" "{$brand.brand_logo|replace:'data/brandlogo/':''}.jpg"}
{if file_exists($bgImg)}
        <img src="data/brandlogo/{$bgImg}" />
     {else}
        {$brand.brand_name}
{/if}
</div>
```

**hope result** (if brand_logo not empty)

```
<div>
<img src="data/brandlogo/logo.jpg" />
</div>
```

**hope result** (if brand_logo empty)

```
 <div>
 <p>northwind_store_name</p>
 </div>
```

i'm not sure my smarty template part is correct or not correct 
i already try to use simple if else smarty code like

```
  <div>
    {if $brand.brand_logo}
            <img src="data/brandlogo/{$brand.brand_logo}" />
         {else}
            {$brand.brand_name}
    {/if}
  </div>
```

but it not work ($brand.brand_logo always not empty!! )
cause the "data/brandlogo/" need used to another php code so i can't remove 
(mark:i'm not sure my smarty version so the smarty code maybe is have two write way style )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't check if the file exists in smarty, do it in php and then send the result (true or false) to smarty.